# What would be the best way to map similar ngrams

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, wordnet

I'm trying to map similar ngrams using Wordnet and synsets. For example: `elder brother` and `older sibling` should map to the same entity.

What would be the best way to implement this? I've been thinking and so far I've only come up with a brute-force approach checking for each synset of each word and trying to find a similar word or else add them as a new entity.

I am wondering whether there are any better methods of implementing this?

for 1-gram:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
l = WordNetLemmatizer()

older = 'older'
elder = 'elder'
older_lemma = l.lemmatize(older, pos=wn.ADJ)
elder_lemma = l.lemmatize(elder, pos=wn.ADJ)


for syn in wn.synsets(older_lemma):
    if elder_lemma in syn.lemma_names():
        print(syn)
```

Ideally, I would want to extend it to n-grams and I'm searching for a better way to do this.